# Custom events firing

Tags: angularjs

I have a question, which I'm not sure how to put, but I will try.

I made custom element, called `matrix`, it has rows and columns. I can select a row and/or column. Now I want, from inside my element, to fire set events: `onRowSelect`, `onColumnSelect`, `onCellSelect`, and pass parameters to any listeners these events might have.

For example:

```
<matrix
  data-on-row-select='onRowSelect'
  data-on-cell-select='foo'>
</matrix>

var controller = function($scope) {
  $scope.onRowSelect = function(a, b, c) { };
  $scope.foo = function(a, b, c) { };
  /* ... */
}
```

How should I declare `scope` of `matrix` directive? How can I fire these events?

Comment: How you 'made' your element matrix?

Comment: How about $broadcast, $emit and $on?

Comment: @Edminsson the question is how can I do this by assigning listeners using attributes.

Comment: @Raghav what do you mean? Using "directive" with "controller" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply bind `onRowSelect` to directive's scope using two-way binding:

```
.directive('matrix', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onRowSelect: '=' 
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      function onRowSelect() {
        if (angular.isFunction($scope.onRowSelect)) {
          $scope.onRowSelect(a, b, c);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS only supports binding to specific events (like click). If you want to subscribe to custom events you need to write your own directive. But you can use the Event Binder directive from the Angular UI library http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/event

Answer (score 0):

A little abstract example of how you could do it (I'd recommend you use the answer suggested by @package though (as it's a wee bit cleaner, in my opinion)).

With my solution, we loop through the passed in arguments and if the property key begins with `on`, we stow it away in an array.

We then loop through the array and setup event listeners for each of the keys in said array, and execute the passed in callback.

```
controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.onRowSelect  = fn();
  $scope.onCellSelect = fn();
}

// HTML
<matrix on-row-select="onRowSelect()" on-cell-select="onCellSelect()"></matrix>

directive('matrix', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      var events = Object.keys(attrs).map(function (prop) {
        if (prop.match(/^on/)) { 
          return prop;
        }
      });

      events.forEach(function (event) {
        if (!!event) {
          scope.$on(event, scope.$eval(attrs[event]));            
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever the corresponding event reaches the scope of `matrix`, it's callback will be executed in the context of the matrix scope.

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/lasajimi/1/edit

**Edit**: I am by no means 'skilled' when it comes to regex, but it seems to have caught on to the correct properties when I tested it out. Hopefully someone can correct me here if it's way off.